# Lectura de caracteres especiales (eñes y tildes) desde un buffer en Java

Tags: java

Si leo un fichero de texto desde java con el código que muestro a continuación, no se interpretan correctamente caracteres especiales como las letras con tilde o eñes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  String cadena, archivo;
  archivo = "D:\\fichero.txt";
  FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
  BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
  while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) {
      System.out.println(cadena);
  }
  b.close();
}
```

En otras consultas leo que que se debe indicar la codificación en el constructor del FileReader (new FileReader(archivo, "UTF-8"); pero me aparecer un error indicando que ningún constructor admite este segundo parámetro.

Me ocurre lo mismo cuando leo caracteres a utilizando un socket. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código, tengo un cliente que envía y recibe texto sobre un socket:

```
socketCliente = new Socket("localhost", 2000);
entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketCliente.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
salida = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketCliente.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8")), true);
stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String linea;
do {
    System.out.print("Entrada: ");
    linea = stdIn.readLine();
    salida.println(linea);
    respuesta = entrada.readLine();
    System.out.println("Respuesta: " + respuesta);
} while (!linea.equalsIgnoreCase("fin"));
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente cuando escribas en el archivo lo tienes que **codificar** a **UTF-8** de igual manera cuando leas el archivo usa la codificación **UTF-8**  ejemplo:

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */
public class LeerEscribirArchivosUTF8 {

    private String file = "D:\\fichero.txt";

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LeerEscribirArchivosUTF8 escribirArchivosUTF8 = new LeerEscribirArchivosUTF8();
        escribirArchivosUTF8.escribirArchivo();
        escribirArchivosUTF8.leerArchivo();
    }

    public void escribirArchivo() throws IOException {

        Writer escribe = null;

        try {
            escribe = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF8"));
            escribe.write("Este es un archivo con codificación utf-8\n"
                    + "Ejemplo:"
                    + "estos son letras con acento y caracteres especiales: áéíóú ñ $ & %");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            escribe.close();
        }
    }

    public void leerArchivo() throws IOException {

        String cadena = "";
        new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true), "UTF8"));

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "utf-8"));
        try {
            while ((cadena = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(cadena);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

    }

}
```